# How can divide a textbook every 400 lines parts with python?

Tags: python

i have 20 files and they all have different number of lines. Mostly 1000+ lines, i want to divide them 400 lines parts with python and save it as a different text files.
How can i do that ? Is **split()** method useful for this?

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Start with a Python tutorial, and then see if you can figure it out. Alternatively, *pay* a programmer to write code for you (this is not the venue to request that, but there are people who will do it elsewhere). But volunteers on StackOverflow are not going to write code at your request for free.

Comment: In order to use `split()` you will first need to read your files. You can save each 400 rows into a new file while reading them.

Answer (score -1):

1. get their names with `glob.glob()`
2. turn each file into list with lines as elements by `f.readlines()`
3. each `f.readlines()` output extend to some `common_list`
4. then iterate this `common_list` appending a line (=`common_list`'s element) to a new file
5. and count lines, every time it's 400th one create a new file